# Webpage images loading correctly without any reference to them?

Tags: html, css

I have some coding experience but I have never seriously dabbled in html or css, and have no idea how webpages work. But now I have this webpage I am trying to update that I inherited, so I do what I must. I was trying to force an image to rescale when viewed on mobile, since it was too big, and the only thing that was not scaling. I tried all sorts of things I found but nothing changed anything!
So I got curious. The only reference to the image is in css file that is recalled in html such as:

```
link href="tools/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I deleted the reference. The image was OK. So I deleted the whole CSS file that takes care of fonts, sizes, and other images. The wepage didnt change. Like WTF. As I said, I have no idea how webpages work, but when I change something in the html index the changes are immediate, wheter it be div style or the actual text/links. How come the images be on the page, when all the references to where to find them are deleted?!

Comment: Have a look in your browser's dev tools (inspect) to see exactly what code has been loaded. You may find that you are constantly getting the same HTML file as it has been cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check how the images are inserted on the site. Via the img tag in HTML or as a background image via CSS. Also try to do a hard reload of the page (Ctrl + F5), if everything is fine, it should show the changes on the page.

Now let's move on to the responsive image. The first thing you need to have is this link in the head tag of your HTML document...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I think this is exactly what will solve your problem. See more about this tag at this link... https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Oh god, it was the cache. 
Well I have  EXACTLY that line there. But the page is still loading weird on phone. There is this one image that just does not rescale, and so the width of the page is the same as the image.
I also added google map and facebook feed, and those do not scale as well, but I fixed those with width: 100%...

Comment: @Vernum Yes, `width: 100%;` or `max-width` will solve most of the problem with responsive elements. Glad I was helpful, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Assets such as CSS and JavaScript are cached, so you need to do a full reload using for example `shift+f5`.
There is also an option in browsers to clear the cache for a website when you click the Lock-icon at the left in the address bar.